# Unknown pseudo-element or pseudo-class :hover

Tags: css, hover, pseudo-class, pseudo-element

I've never really paid this close attention but I'm getting the following error:

```
Unknown pseudo-element or pseudo-class :hover
```

on the following code

```
A:hover { COLOR: #F56655; text-decoration: underline; }
```

Since when has :hover not been valid css and what is the alternative?

I have seen this used everywhere...

Comment: `:hover` only works for a in IE.

Comment: it appears to work fine in Firefox? 
Does this mean that hover should never be used?

Comment: @Babiker: is that true of *all* IE? I was under the impression it was only IE <= 6 that suffered that problem; albeit that IE 7 required a Doctype to knock it into standards-compliant mode.

Comment: no, it just means that (some?) IE users will have a degraded (or *less-upgraded*) experience.

Comment: My issue is with w3c compliance.  These are all displaying as errors (not warnings) I guess it means I have to remove all hover attributes if I want my website to be compliant?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Double check your validation rules, testing here I get no errors, using CSS 2.1:

http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/

If you're testing **CSS 1.0 compliance**, you'll get your exact error, since `:hover` [wasn't in CSS 1.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-CSS1/#anchor-pseudo-classes), it was [added in 2.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#dynamic-pseudo-classes).

Comment: I'm testing WITH http://validator.w3.org/mobile for mobile ... I assume mobile css doesn't like hover

Comment: You can always check what CSS attributes are compatible with mobile devices here: http://www.quirksmode.org/m/css.html

Answer (score 1):

I believe it's just your capital A, use a lowercase and should be fine.